# How to map a SOAP XML response to a DataContract ContractMember List<string> in UWP on Win IoT

Tags: xml, soap, uwp, response

I need to map a SOAP XML response elements to a DataContract, DataMember List in UWP on Win IoT. The SOAP XML response elements with generic data types map correctly. But the XML elements of type (Cal in this case):

```
    <ConfigPackageResult xmlns= myNamespace> 
        ...
        <Cal>    
            <CD>string</CD>    
            <CD>string</CD>       
            ...    
            <CD>string</CD>    
            <CD>string</CD>    
            <CD>string</CD>    
        </Cal>
        ...
    </ConfigPackageResult>
```

map to an empty list. Here are the DataContract DataMember and the separate DataContract of the string entries:

```
   [DataContract(Namespace = myNamespace)]
   public sealed class ConfigPackage
   {
         ....
         [DataMember(IsRequired = false, Name = "Cal", Order = 10)]
         public IList<CalendarEntry> Cal { get; set; }
         ...

   }

   [DataContract(Namespace = myNamespace)]
   public sealed class CalendarEntry
   {
        [DataMember(Name = "CD")]
        public string CD { get; set; }
   }
```

I was not able to find an appropriate example of deserializing SOAP response XML package elements to UWP collections for Win IoT.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Please try to use [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) to serialize and deserialize objects into and from XML documents.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to deserialize the IList component by using a neat workaround but will look at XmlSerializer.